# Calculating company-wise total expenses

Tags: java

I have a variable List. Its declaration is like :

> ```
> List<HashMap<String, Object>>
> ```

Sample data in it:

> [{total-expense=228, company=HiHard, year=2009}, {total-expense=2936, company=POTENT, year=2009}, {total-expense=1362412.65, company=HiHard, year=2010}, {total-expense=9007.96, company=POTENT, year=2010}, {total-expense=240427.43, company=HiHard, year=2011}, {total-expense=1956.11, company=POTENT, year=2011}]

I have written a program to fetch the below result:

> {"HiHard":[[228,1362412.65,240427.43]],"POTENT":[[2936,9007.96,1956.11]]}

i.e. to fetch company-wise total expense incurred for financial years 2009, 2010, 2011.

**Current program logic:**

1) getDistinctCompanies from the list

2) Iterate through the distinct companies[from step 1] and get the expense incurred by passing in company and list.

**Complete program:**

```
public class JSONConstruction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        ... ASSUME list has the SAMPLE data as described before.

        List<String> companyList = getDistinctCompanies(list);

        Iterator<String> iterCompany = companyList.iterator();
        String company;
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        while(iterCompany.hasNext()){
            company = iterCompany.next();
            JSONArray jsonList = new JSONArray();
            jsonList.add(getExpenseList(list, company));
            obj.put(company, jsonList);
        }

        System.out.print(obj);
    }

    private static List<String> getDistinctCompanies(List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
        Iterator<HashMap<String, Object>> iterList = list.iterator();
        String company;
        List<String> companyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (iterList.hasNext()) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = iterList.next();
            company = (String) map.get("company");
            if(companyList==null || (!companyList.contains(company))) {
                companyList.add(company);
            }
        }
        return companyList;
    }

    private static List<Object> getExpenseList(List<HashMap<String, Object>> list, String company) {
        Iterator<HashMap<String, Object>> iterList = list.iterator();
        List<Object> expenseList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        String companyMatch;
        while (iterList.hasNext()) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = iterList.next();
            companyMatch = (String) map.get("company");
            if(companyMatch.equals(company)) {
                Object obj = map.get("total-expense");
                expenseList.add(obj);
            }
        }
        return expenseList;
    }
```

Though the data is fetched correctly, I am eager to know a better way of coding this program.

Comment: Why is each value a list of lists instead of just a one-dimensional list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Interfaces over implementations type declaration

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
```

Favoring interfaces over implementations for type declaration applies to nested generic types as well, meaning the above can be better represented as:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
// or Java 7 and greater
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

## Enforcing distinct values

A [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of a `List` makes for a better representation of a distinct collection of values, as its API mandates no duplicate elements. As such, your `getDistinctCompanies()` method should return a `Set`. In addition, the `if`-check is redundant as you can freely call the [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) method with the guarantee that duplicate elements will not be added:

```
private static Set<String> getDistinctCompanies(List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
    Set<String> companyList = new HashSet<>();
    // Using for-each loop
    for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
        companyList.add((String) map.get("company"));
    }
    return companyList;
}
```

## Java 8

Processing a `Collection` of elements can often be made simpler using Java 8's streams.

For your use case, what you are doing are just:

1. From each `Map` element of `list`, extract the `company` and `total-expense` values.
2. Group `total-expense` into a `List` by the `company` names.
3. Use each `company` name as the key of a `JSONObject`, with a `JSONArray` wrapper over the `total-expense` values as the value.

You can generate an intermediary `Map<String, List<Object>` result to represent the one-to-many `company` \$\to\$ `total-expense` processing from steps 1 and 2:

```
private static Map<String, List<Object>> getTotalExpensesByCompany(
        List<Map<String, Object>> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .map(m -> Collections.singletonMap((String) m.get("company"), 
                                                m.get("total-expense")))
            .map(Map::entrySet)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
}
```

The [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) 'converts' each stream element as the desired `company` \$\to\$ `total-expense` mapping, before [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)-ping to a `Stream` of `Entry` objects. This is then collected into the resulting `Map` [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) the `Entry`'s key (using `Entry::getKey` as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)), and [`mapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) all the values (`Entry::getValue`) [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
Map<String, List<Object>> map = getTotalExpensesByCompany(list);
map.forEach((k ,v) -> result.put(k, new JSONArray().put(v)));
```

Step 3 is to call your `JSONObject/JSONArray` operations [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) of the key-value entries in the `Map`, as shown above. A more succinct way can also be:

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
getTotalExpensesByCompany(list).forEach((k ,v) -> result.put(k, new JSONArray().put(v)));
```

Also, if [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112311/calculating-company-wise-total-expenses/112437#comment207436_112311)'s comment is right and what you need is actually a one-dimensional list for `JSONArray`, use `new JSONArray(v)` instead.

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> private static List<String> getDistinctCompanies(List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
>     Iterator<HashMap<String, Object>> iterList = list.iterator();
>     String company;
>     List<String> companyList = new ArrayList<String>();
>     while (iterList.hasNext()) {
>         HashMap<String, Object> map = iterList.next();
>         company = (String) map.get("company");
>         if(companyList==null || (!companyList.contains(company))) {
>             companyList.add(company);
>         }
>     }
>     return companyList;
> }
> ```

- There is no need to check if `companyList==null` because that won't ever happen because 4 lines prior you create the list.
- The scope of `map` is defined to be inside the `while` loop, but `company` is defined outside whereas it is only used in the while loop as well.
- You should name your variables proper. Shortening names doesn't add any value. Instead of `iterList` a simple `iterator` or `listIterator` would be much better.
- You should leave your variables and operators some space to breathe. This helps to make your code more readable. `companyList==null` vs `companyList == null`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It would be nice to know if you can share a better logic(alogorithm)